# Field 'date' doesn't have a default value while getting date value

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently trying to get 'date' value from HTML for birthdays. 
But I get this error: **SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'date' doesn't have a default value**

Is this error related to date formats? My system uses 'dd-mm-yyyy' format but Laravel uses 'yyyy-mm-dd' format. Is that the cause to it?

**Controller**

```
public function store(StorePersonRequest $request)
    {
        $person = new Person;

        $person->name = $request->get('person_name');
        $person->surname = $request->get('person_surname');
        $person->name = $request->get('person_date');

        $person->save();
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="person_date" required autofocus>
```

**Migration**

```
$table->date('date');
```

I've already added `protected $dates = ['date'];` but it didn't solved the problem.

Comment: isnt it $person->date = $request->get('person_date');

Comment: I'm the dumbest guy. Thank you by the way.

Comment: you can also use Carbon::createFromFormat('input_date_format', 'input_value')->toDateString();

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
$person->name = $request->get('person_date');
```

to this:

```
$person->date= $request->get('person_date');
```